# ERROE using Auto Py to Exe

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, auto-py-to-exe

When I try to convert my PY file into a EXE file using pip install auto-py-to-exe the EXE file does not work.

I found the following ERROR in the program console, if anyone can help me how to solve this please?:

My Anaconda version is 1.9.12

PYTHONPATH is OK.

The error is the following when trying to get the .exe file:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.7.6
Building directory: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed  "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Scripts\Italiano\conjugacion_verbos_presente\auxiliar.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Scripts\Italiano\conjugacion_verbos_presente\auxiliar.py --distpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\application --workpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build --specpath C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8

25449 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
25457 INFO: Python: 3.7.6 (conda)
25461 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
25466 INFO: wrote C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\auxiliar.spec
25471 INFO: UPX is not available.
25478 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python\\Scripts\\Italiano',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfe01rrs8']
25483 INFO: checking Analysis
25490 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
25495 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
25509 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
25522 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
30874 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
31033 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
31063 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
31536 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Scripts\Italiano\conjugacion_verbos_presente\auxiliar.py
32955 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
32962 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib'
35478 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
36417 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
36422 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
42146 INFO: Processing module hooks...
42152 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
42160 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
42300 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
42310 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
42679 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
42686 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
43667 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
44393 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
44400 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
44406 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
44414 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
45197 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
45977 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
47242 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
47248 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
48280 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
48288 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
48450 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
48709 INFO: checking Tree
48714 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
48722 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
48812 INFO: checking Tree
48817 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
48825 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
48880 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
48948 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
48961 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
48969 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
48977 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
48989 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
49015 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
49032 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_ilp64.dll
49119 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90rtl.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
49125 WARNING: lib not found: pgf90.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
49140 WARNING: lib not found: pgc14.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_pgi_thread.dll
49153 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_ilp64.dll
49552 WARNING: lib not found: msmpi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_msmpi_lp64.dll
49770 WARNING: lib not found: mpich2mpi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_mpich2_lp64.dll
49784 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_ilp64.dll
49799 WARNING: lib not found: impi.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.dll
50206 WARNING: lib not found: libssl-1_1-x64.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
50215 WARNING: lib not found: libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
50235 WARNING: lib not found: libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll dependency of C:\Anaconda3\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
50724 INFO: Looking for eggs
50729 INFO: Using Python library C:\Anaconda3\python37.dll
50740 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
50761 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build\auxiliar\warn-auxiliar.txt
50898 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build\auxiliar\xref-auxiliar.html
50949 INFO: checking PYZ
50957 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
50966 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build\auxiliar\PYZ-00.pyz
52954 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build\auxiliar\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
52990 INFO: checking PKG
52999 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
53011 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
53067 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
53078 INFO: Bootloader C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
53090 INFO: checking EXE
53105 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
53122 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
53137 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfe01rrs8\build\auxiliar\auxiliar.exe
53159 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
53177 INFO: checking COLLECT
53190 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
53207 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
59025 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Scripts\Italiano\conjugacion_verbos_presente\output
Complete.
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: FInally the numpy module was giving troubles. Even though I could run the program